# How do I check with a Bash script if an application is running?

Tags: bash, gnome, process-management, pgrep

I have a gnome-run application in my home folder. I have now added the application to run when I press <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (I added it in in [CCSM](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM)). I run the application by executing `./gnome-run` in my home folder.
I can't find any trace of the application process in the output of `ps -A`.

The problem is that if I have the gnome-run program open and I press the key combination I want the application to close. Is there a way to create a bash file that checks if the applications is running? If it is then close it, else launch it.

Comment: have you tried `pgrep`? eg `pgrep xterm` returns the pids of my running xterm's. You could check if your app is already running using this (run `pgrep yourapp` and check if it's return code is 0 or 1 using `echo $?`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This shell script should handle the starting and stopping of any program:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASECMD=${1%%\ *}
PID=$(pgrep "$BASECMD")
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "at least one instance of "$BASECMD" found, killing all instances"
    kill $PID
else
    echo "no running instances of "$BASECMD" found, starting one"
    $1
 fi
```

let's say you saved it under `~/mystarter`, you can run any command with it using `~/mystarter <name>`, eg in your case, bind <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to:

```
~/mystarter gnome-run
```

and make sure the script is executable: `chmod u+x ~/mystarter`. Also it's probably best to put it somewhere in your `PATH`, so you don't have to type it's full location every time.

As for the fact that `gnome-run` doesn't show up in `ps -A`, make sure that gnome run itself isn't a script that launches the actual process. Check if there is a difference between `ps -A | wc -l` before and after launching it (this counts all running processes).

#### Edit:

Since you've accepted the answer, I thought I'd add support for running commands that have commandline arguments, so that this might become a place of reference. Run a command like so:

```
 ./mystarter 'cmd args'
```

eg:

```
./mystarter 'ncmpcpp -c ~/.ncmpcpp'
```

The command just looks up `ncmpcpp` to see if it's running already, but executes the full command (with arguments) when `ncmpcpp` wasn't running.